# gulp-imagemin how to get the, compressed value, to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, compression, imagemin

I have tried to get the compressed value of: original size, minified size and space savings to a variable. So far only plugins that I have found are showing this data only in console.

[image]

Is there any easy way to get the same data displayed in the console to a variable?

My code for gulp-imagemin:

```
    gulp.task("compress-images", () =>
    Promise.all([
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gulp
          .src("./uploads/*")
          .pipe(printSpaceSavings.init())
          .pipe(
            imagemin([
              imageminMozjpeg({ quality: 75 }),
              imagemin.svgo({
                plugins: [{ removeViewBox: true }, { cleanupIDs: false }]
              })
            ])
          )
          .pipe(
            tap(function(file) {
              file.contents = Buffer.from(
                yourFunction(file.contents.toString())
              );
              function yourFunction(input) {
                return input.toString(); // Possible to get this data to a variable?
              }
            })
          )
          .on("error", reject)
          .pipe(printSpaceSavings.print()) //consoleLog
          .pipe(gulp.dest("./compressed"))
          .on("end", resolve);
      })
    ])
  );
```

Comment: why do you want it in a variable ? whats the purpose ?

Comment: To display the value with the image on front-end

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the scope of the variable will remain after the gulp task finishes( as I do not know how your code is structured), so one suggestion I could give you would be to write the value to a file and retrieve it from it for displaying in the front-end.

Comment: I just think its so weird that you can access the data and show it in a console, but can't access it, so that you can get the data to show as an variable. But yeah I think I have to retrieve the data again so that I can show it in front-end.